# Perl: Fastest way to find files older than X number of minutes, sorted oldest to newest?

Tags: perl, file, sorting, find

=================

**1. Find the files older than X number of minutes**

**2. Process them from oldest to newest**

The Code below works fine, however the directory contains 3 millions of files. Hence I need to optimize it to find the files faster. I don't have to worry about the content of the file just the name.

```
###########################
sub get_files_to_process{
###########################
# Declare arrays
my @xmlfiles;
my @qulfiedfiles; 

# Declare a Dictionary
my %filedisc;

opendir(my $dh, $maindir) or die "opendir($maindir): $!";

 # Read all the files
 while (my $de = readdir($dh)) {
    # get the Full path of the file
    my $f = $maindir . $de;
    # If File is there and has .xml Extension
    if ( -f $f && $f=~ /\.xml/){
       # Put it in a XMLFILES Array
       push (@xmlfiles, $f); }
    }
    closedir($dh);


 # For every file in directory
 for my $file (@xmlfiles) {

    # Get stats about a file
    my @stats = stat($file);

    # If time stamp is older than minutes provided
    if ($stats[9] <= ($now - (( $minutesold * 60) ))){

       # Put the File and Time stamp in the dictionary
       $filedisc{$file} = $stats[9];
    }
 }

# For every file in the dictionary sort based on the timestamp oldest files first
 for my $x (sort {$filedisc{$a} <=> $filedisc{$b} or $a cmp $b } keys %filedisc) {

    # Put the qualified files (Based on the age) in a list
       push(@qulfiedfiles, $x);}
```

**UPDATE: So far this seems promising, more testing to be done:**

```
##########################
sub get_files_count{
##########################

   my $cmd= "find $maindir -maxdepth 1 -name '*.xml' -mmin +$minutesold -printf \"%T+\t%p\\n\"| sort";
   my @output = `$cmd`;

   if (@output){
      foreach my $line (@output){
            chomp $line;
            push (@files2process, ( split '\t', $line )[ -1 ]);
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: I haven't tested your code on a directory with 3_000_000 entries.  Before we start talking about ways to optimize the code, why don't you use `Devel::NYTProf` to determine where your code is spending the most time?

Comment: How are you processing the files once you have your list?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot , Once I have the list of file, I based on the name of the file I move the file to appropriate sub-directories (and create the sub-dir if not already there), this script would run out of cron every 5 to 10 mins, Enterpise application generates tons of  xml files and this would groom those files

Comment: @DavidO Thanks for your comment. I'll put that in and see, but I'm pretty sure the most of the time is spent in stating the file all the files in order to get a list of oldest to newest.

Comment: If the bulk of your time is spent in `stat` (I believe you are correct), then the goal should be to make as few calls to `stat` as possible, in any of its forms.  your `-f` tests are also making internal system `stat` calls.  So instead of invoking `-f` *and* later making a call to `stat`, make a single call to `stat` (which also provides "type" similar to `-f`), and cache the portion of the results you will use later.  Also, you only need to make that call to `stat` if `$f =~ /\.xml$/`, so do the regexp test *first*, and the stat call only if the regex call succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

Use File::Find

```
use File::Find

$\ = "\n";

my @files;

# find all files newer that 9 minutes
File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, '.');

# sort them and print them
print for map { $_-[0] }  sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] } @files;

exit;

sub wanted {
   ((-M) < (9 / (24 * 60))) && -f && push @files, [ $_, ( -M ) ];
}
```

This is recursive - so it will go through all sub-directories (but I assume from your question there are none).

Also, the above is mostly auto-generated code from find2perl, which translates most of unix find parameters into a perl script - cool and fast.

I haven't tested the -M bit with the 9 minutes - I haven't saved anything in the last 9 minutes.

Comment: Have you compared the run time of this suggestion to what the OP is currently using, or is it just intuition that it will be significantly faster?  ...because we wouldn't want to get too excited about insignificant improvements, or regressions.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this in two steps:

1) create an [Linux::Inotify2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Linux::Inotify2) process, what at every change on the directory would updates some cahce file (like Storable or such)

*e.g. you will have an actual cache of all file-stats. Loading one Storable file is faster as gathering stats for 3M files at every run*

2) when need search, only load the Storable, a search one big hash...

Comment: Thanks for your input. That is a very clever solution and i'll definitely look into it. Unfortunately this being enterprise application there are lot of other caveats.

Comment: @Grene just commented you this once again with the same comment. So, probably still fighting with the question. Could you please be more specific? E.g. the used OS and such? And you said in a comment _and this would groom those files_ - so, when you once moved them to subdirs, how they count could be 3_000_000 again in some short time interval so you need such extreme stat speed? It sounds for me as a nonsense... Please, ask an real question - not a hypotetical one - otherwise, you can't get any relevant answers...

Comment: Sorry I was just correcting a typo in my comment. As I have posted update on the question it is working within an acceptable time range and much faster then what I had before. Just more information, The issue is real , the script is to run every 30 mins, the application generates around ~100k xml files in that time frame, however the initial backlog of the files is really huge and mounted over NFS. To process the files in order they were generated takes a long time. The script is part of bigger application so sorry I didn't provide enough details.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question. I am mostly answering it for the "future generations".

Most of your time is very likely spent in *sorting* the 3 million file entries, because sort operations are non-linear (ie sorting becomes slower and slower the more files you have), and also because most of the stat calls occur in the comparisons, which mostly occur due to sort.
(Also the file list will probably occupy quite a chunk of your memory.)

So if you can avoid sorting, you will also automatically avoid most of the stat calls and save a ton of time. Since your task is just "moving the files into appropriate directories" I would simply call the processing method for each file you find that fits your criteria, **the moment you find it**, as opposed to first creating an enormous list, use a bunch of cycles to sort it, and then going through the enormous list and process it in a way that doesn't necessarily need sorting in the first place.

An example from your own script: "find", unlike say "ls", does *not* create a file list in memory -- it executes the commands for each file the moment it finds it. Which is why it doesn't explode with enormous directories, unlike "ls". Just do it like find does it ^^